# JQuery/CSS Transitions: Easier way without using negative margins?

Tags: jquery, cordova, margin, transition, hidden

I have a PhoneGap/Cordova project that means I must use a combination of JQuery and CSS transitions to achieve animations (JQuery animations are chunky on iOS).

I have made some code that implements a series of drop downs, however I think it is badly done and I am looking for some advice on how to improve it.

My main concern is the positioning of the divs, especially the use of negative margins.

If I were to change the length of a div it would through everything out of alignment - I have to apply a negative margin-top to get them to display at the top of the screen, other wise they would sit down the bottom as if they had loaded normally, one after the other.

Also, I get a large amount of white space at the bottom of the page where the divs are *supposed* to be, had the translate not been applied to them.

CSS:

```
#dropdiv1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}

#dropdiv2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3400px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}

#dropdiv3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4200px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#clickme1').click(
                      function() {
                      $('#dropdiv1').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -335px)');
                      });

  $('#clickme2').click(
                        function() {
                        $('#dropdiv2').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -2335px)');
                        });

  $('#clickme3').click(
                        function() {
                        $('#dropdiv3').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -3300px)');
                        });
```

Comment: I've rephrased the question a little better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202076/webkit-transform-using-positionabsolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to the css - adding position: absolute and a z-index to the #dropdivs. This solves the problem of them 'stacking up' on and each other. I then position each div under its respective #clickme div/button so that when it appeared it would appear in a proper position.

The only negative about this is that I had to set the height of my page to accomodate the tallest #dropdiv when it is shown, otherwise the bottom of the page would cut it off.

My code:

```
<div id="bigcontainer">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
     <li><a id="clickme1" href="#">Click Me 1</a></li>
                    <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv1">
                        Lots of random text....
                </div>
 <li><a id="clickme2" href="#">Click Me 2</a></li>
                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv2">
                    Lots of random text....
                </div>     
 <li><a id="clickme3" href="#">Click Me 3</a></li>
                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv3">
                   Lots of random text....
                </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigcontainer {
height: 1500px;/*as big as the bigest dropdiv to enable scrolling*/
}    

#dropdiv1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

#dropdiv2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3400px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}

#dropdiv3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4200px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
}
```