# -webkit-transform: using position:absolute

Tags: jquery, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a series of divs that slide down using `-webkit-transform` from a negative margin-top to a position on the screen. Problem is that they end up where they would normally be sitting if there was no negetive margin-top applied to them.

This means if I show the 2nd div it has an empty space the size of the first div above it. To solve this I can apply a negative margin-top to the 2nd div, but I think thats messy.

My main concern is that if the height of dropdiv1 changes then I would have to reset the values on the click functions to have the other divs line up correctly again when shown.

Is there a way to amend `-webkit-transform` to incorporate postion:absolute?

My current code is:

CSS:

```
#dropdiv1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}

#dropdiv2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3400px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}

#dropdiv3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4200px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#clickme1').click(
                      function() {
                      $('#dropdiv1').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -335px)');
                      });

  $('#clickme2').click(
                        function() {
                        $('#dropdiv2').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -2335px)');
                        });

  $('#clickme3').click(
                        function() {
                        $('#dropdiv3').css('-webkit-transform','translate(0, -3300px)');
                        });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="mainmenu">
 <li><a id="clickme1" href="#">Click Me 1</a></li>
 <li><a id="clickme2" href="#">Click Me 2</a></li>     
 <li><a id="clickme3" href="#">Click Me 3</a></li>
</ul>

                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv1">
                    Lots of random text....
                </div>

                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv2">
                    Lots of random text....
                </div>

                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv3">
                   Lots of random text....
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have found a kind of solution. Still messy but ok:

```
<div id="bigcontainer">
    <ul class="mainmenu">
     <li><a id="clickme1" href="#">Click Me 1</a></li>
                    <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv1">
                        Lots of random text....
                </div>
 <li><a id="clickme2" href="#">Click Me 2</a></li>
                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv2">
                    Lots of random text....
                </div>     
 <li><a id="clickme3" href="#">Click Me 3</a></li>
                <div class="showdata"  id="dropdiv3">
                   Lots of random text....
                </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigcontainer {
height: 1500px;/*as big as the bigest dropdiv to enable scrolling*/
}    

#dropdiv1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}

#dropdiv2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3400px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
}

#dropdiv3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4200px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Not particularly a fan but it will do!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any logical behavior for animating `position: absolute`.

This would be more easy to read:

```
#dropdiv1 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3000px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
#dropdiv1.anim {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -335px);
}

#dropdiv2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3400px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
#dropdiv2.anim {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2335px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}

#dropdiv3 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -4200px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
#dropdiv3.anim {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -3300px);
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in 1s;
}
```

Then add class instead.

```
$('#dropdiv3').addClass('anim');
```

That, or either run a `.offset()` before applying `position: absolute` and use that `top` and `left` for animation.

Comment: Thanks Robin, but my concern is more if I have to add more content to say dropdiv1 then that would require me resetting the negative postions of all other divs - eg: if I add 20px to driodiv1's height I would have to add 20px to the other divs to make sure they line up properly again when shown

Comment: Couldn't you create a function that measured and positioned the three boxes accordlingly and have it run upon height or content change?

Comment: Hmm I dont really have the skill level to do that... Could it be achieved with z-indexes or position absolute at all?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm starting to get confused about what you're actually after.

Comment: Yeah it is a bit hard to explain. I have added the HTML above to try and help. Basically, though the 3 dropdivs are 'hidden' above the page before they are clicked, there is still white space below the ul where they would normally sit. So for example if I clicked clickme2 to show dropdiv2 it would appear halfway down the page with white space the height of dropdiv1 above it and white space the height of dropdiv3 below it. Hence I have used the negative margins to position it further up the page ... hope that helps!